# Why is my ajax call returning null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, echo

So I am doing an ajax call, that is working, to grab some xml from my REST API.

When I echo the results I get, JQuery is saying that the return from ajax is null.

When I var_dump the results instead, the information is accepted by JQuery, but is obviously not formatted correctly, so it errors out.

Here is the jquery, which works fine.

```
$('.trackLine').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.kazark.meacloudserver.com/index.php/search/Video/Zoolander",
        dataType : "xml",
        type:"GET",

        //Successfull grabbed from API
        success: function( xml ) {
            xml = $.parseXML( xml );
            //xml = xml[OperationRequest];
            xml = xml.find( "title" );
            console.log("is this shit here " +xml);
            $( "<h1>" ).text( xml.title ).appendTo( "body" );
            $( "<div class=\"content\">").html( xml.html ).appendTo( "body" );
        },


        // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
        // status codes are passed to the function
        error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
            alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
            console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
            console.log( "Status: " + status );
            console.dir( xhr );
        },
        // Code to run regardless of success or failure
        complete: function( xhr, status ) {
            alert( "The request is complete!" );
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my REST API php which works fine as well, except for the echo

```
$app->get('/search/:category/:term', function ($term, $category) {
$attributes = amazonCall($term, $category, null, null, true);

//var_dump($attributes);
echo "$attributes";
//echo"SOME STUFF";

/*
*/
```

});

both the var_dump and echoing some stuff return correctly to the js, but when I try the echo "$attributes", my JQuery says "TypeError: xml is null"

Also accessing the url in my browser works fine as well, echoing $attributes as I expected.

Please help! Thank you

Comment: does echoing anything work? If you echo "SOME STUFF", what does jquery pick up?

Comment: What is the result of `$attributes`.. if it is not properly formatted xml it will fail, because you've set the dataType to xml in your jQuery ajax

Comment: it picks up "SOME STUFF" fine and well

Comment: It is validated xml, but when it does that it tells me that it is invalid XML, instead of just returning "xml is null" but thanks

Comment: are you setting the content-type in php? I've had issues before with jQuery & requesting JSON and the content type not being set. `header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: As for if the quotes are messing it up the echo, Thanks! I actually tried that, it literally doesn't matter either way in this case, it still returns xml is null

Comment: Have a look at your XHR requests in your web developer console.. see what the response looks like, it may be a same-origin policy issue? [info on same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems changing the data- type in jquery to
    dataType : "text"

did the trick
now in the console it says:
is this stuff here [object XMLDocument]

which means its working (I think)
now I just have to figure out how to manipulate this object

Thanks everyone!
your speed responses are very appriciated.